# Soundness Proof for Finitely-valued truth-functional Gödel Semantics with respect to Intuitionstic Propositional Calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was trying to prove the soundness of G_k (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic), i.e.,

if $\Gamma \vdash_{IPC} \varphi $ then $\Gamma \vDash_{G_k} \varphi $

where $\varphi$ is a formula, and $\Gamma$ is a set of formulae.

My idea was to follow the usual proof used to show the soundness of CPC, as found on p. 215-218 of Language, Proof, and Logic by Barwise-Etchemendy.
The idea here is that we are assuming for contradiction that there is some $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma \vdash_{IPC} \varphi $ but $\Gamma \not \vDash_{G_k} \varphi $. Namely, given such a $\varphi$, we would have some truth-assignment $v$ such that $v(\Gamma)=1$ but $v(\varphi) \neq 1$.
We then look through the proof of $\varphi$ and find the first line in the proof which is not a validity in $G_k$, i.e., the first line containing an entry $C$ such that $\Gamma \not \models_{G_K} C$. We then ask which inference rule was used to obtain $C$, and show that every inference rule does preserve validity, as we are assuming all prior lines were validities. I have managed the proof for all the inferences, except for $\supset$ Intro (or $\rightarrow$ Intro, however you want to call it). The result is easy in bivalent logics, but I cannot make sense of it for $3$-valued logics or higher.

The skeleton of the fitch-proof would look like:
[image]

What we have is that $v(\Gamma)=1$, if $v(A)=1$ then $v(B)=1$.

We want to show thet $v(A \supset B)=1$, which amounts to showing that $v(A) \leq v(B)$.

I am not sure how this follows, since I can imagine the following situation that satisfies what we must have, but does not give the result. Namely, I am thinking of being in $G_3$ (3-valued logic), and having $v(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $v(B)=0$. Then $v(A \supset B)=0$, so we do not get the desired result, but it can still be the case that $v(\Gamma)=1$ and this hypothetical value of $v(B)$ given $v(A)$ is the case.

Any suggestions on how to fix this proof would be appreciated. I would very much like to do this proof using the version of Intuitionistic propositional calculus that is minimalist propositional calculus + ex falso quodlibet rule, rather than say, the version of IPC that is defined using a Hilbert-style calculus or the Łukasiewicz version.

Comment: I realized my question was just because I did not understand a definition. Please feel free to delete this post if that's the policy for when questions are asked incorrectly. I won't delete it myself, since it says that "Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking." And in any case, someone may have had the same definitional confusion as me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Entailment in $G_k$ of the form $\Gamma \models_{G_K} \varphi$ is defined not, as I thought, by if $v(\Gamma)=1$ then $v(\varphi)=1$, but rather by $v(\Gamma) \leq v(\varphi)$. This makes the above proof for $\supset$-Intro easy to show, just cash out the definitions.